# \underline appearing too low in MathJax

Tags: vector, latex, mathjax, underline

I prefer to write vectors with the underline symbol:

```
$\underline{x} \; \underline{x}_k \; \underline{y}  \; \underline{z}$
```

But when I do this in MathJax, the appearence is much different from "normal" LaTeX to PDF workflow; the spacing is much higher.

Normal LaTeX: [image: Normal LaTeX]

MathJax: [image: MathJax]

The underlines in MathJax are placed lower than they should.

How can I adjust the distance between a symbol and its underline in MathJax?

Here an other example:

```
$\underline{x} \, \underline{\smash{x}} \, \underline{y} \, \underline{\smash{y}} 
\quad \underline{x}_k \, \underline{\smash{x}}_k \, \underline{y}_k \, \underline{\smash{y}}_k 
\quad \underline{x}{}_k \, \underline{\smash{x}}{}_k \, \underline{y}{}_k \, \underline{\smash{y}}{}_k $
```

LaTeX:
[image: LaTeX]

MathJax:
[image: MathJax]

Comment: Try with `\underline{\smash{x}}` and/or `\underline{x}{}_k`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added your method in my question. But \smash doesnt really change much with the x. However it places the underline even too high for the y.

Comment: You're going to be stuck fiddling around with this and probably having minute corrections for each different style in the future. MathJax is not really LaTeX and therefore doesn't implement in the same way.